# Powershell - disable signature check

Tags: powershell, signature

I have a scheduled task that runs at the same time everyday. It runs a small Powershell script that is unsigned. Since updating Windows 11 to 22H2, I get a prompt from the firewall that Powershell is attempting to connect to the Internet. It's trying to connect to sv.symcb.com or one of the Digicert sites so I assume that this is a cert check for an app signature but I'm not sure.

To be clear, the script does run and completes it's task. I just want it to stop trying to access the Internet. Is there anyway to stop Powershell from attempting to connect to the Internet when this script is ran?

Below are the arguments for the scheduled task:

```
-WindowStyle Hidden -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "C:\path-to\script.ps1"
```

Below is the script:

```
Param (
    # vCenter server & credintials
    [string]$VIServer = "192.168.224.123",
    [string]$User = 'administrator@vsphere.loc',
    [string]$Password = 'xxxxxxx',
    
    [string]$ConfigPath = "C:\path-to\backups\",
    [int]$Days = 21
)
Import-Module VMware.PowerCLI
$Time = Get-Date -Format "MM-dd-yy-hhmm"
If (-not (Test-Path $ConfigPath\Old))
{   New-Item $ConfigPath\Old -ItemType Directory
}
# Add date/time to the configuration file name and move to archive
ForEach ($File in (Get-ChildItem $ConfigPath\*.tgz))
{   $NewName = "$($File.Basename)-$Time.tgz"
    Copy-Item $File.FullName "$ConfigPath\Old\$NewName"
    Remove-Item $File.FullName
}
# Download latest configuration files
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
Connect-VIServer $VIServer -User $User -Password $Password -Force
Get-VMHost | Get-VMHostFirmware -BackupConfiguration -DestinationPath $ConfigPath
# Remove older files in archive
ForEach ($File in (Get-ChildItem $ConfigPath\Old\*.tgz | Where LastWriteTime -LE (Get-Date).AddDays(-$Days)))
{   Remove-Item $File.FullName
}

# Disconnect from vCenter
Disconnect-VIServer -Server $VIServer -Confirm:$false
```

Comment: [`-NoProfile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe)?

Comment: Since Windows 11 22H2 there is a new feature called [Smart App Control](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/what-is-smart-app-control-285ea03d-fa88-4d56-882e-6698afdb7003). It only permits to run signed executables (with some exceptions of widely used unsigned ones). To fully verify a signature it has to make an internet connection to ensure the certificate is not revoked. This would explain connections to both DigiCert and symcb.com (a domain [registered](https://otx.alienvault.com/indicator/domain/symcb.com) by Symantec, who also provide signing services).

Comment: Can you confirm you have Smart App Control activated or running in evaluation mode? You'll find it in Windows settings app.

Comment: Smart App Control was turned off long ago. When you turn off Smart App Control in Windows 11, it is permanently disabled and you can't turn it back on

Comment: @iRon I never setup a profile.  If I run $Profile, it lists C:\Users\Jeff\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1 but that file is not there and there are no .ps1 files in C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0, either. I guess I can add -NoProfile as an argument in the scheduled task just to see if it makes a difference

Comment: Yes, your profile (which could be setup by something else) could be anywhere in the `$env:PSProfileParh`. Also for security it is better to exclude the profile.

Comment: Having a closer look at your script, it's propably the `Connect-VIServer` call that causes the internet connection for verifying the server certificates.